# How to add a view controller to window programmatically and bring it to front

Tags: ios, swift

[image]
I want to do a screen saver for the whole app, but i only can do for 1 screen...now i am changing to appdelegate to start the timer and show the screen saver as a whole...However, i not sure how to add the video screen saver(video player view) as a whole at app delegate window... Timer i did edi, it really print out "Play Video" after 5 second, but the video view didn't show out.

library used:
1. https://github.com/piemonte/Player
2. timer

Comment: you need to add it to the launcher or in some particular case??

Comment: thanks for ur fast reply...any link to learn that, add something to the launcher?

Comment: i am first time posting question at stackoverflow, and i really need someone to guide me...i am an intern student...really sorry, i am not that pro...

Comment: No problem do let me know where exactly you are stuck I will be ready to help you :)

Comment: Why you are using timer for this??

Comment: func startTimer(){
        print("start Timer")
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: self.timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(self.playVideo), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

Comment: Timer is like i can set the time interval to show up the video... like after 5seconds or 10 seconds the video will pop out

Comment: okay fine but why you need timer for this thing, do you want play video for a specific time or for the total duration of the video

Comment: okay you want the video to play after 5 seconds after your application launch right??

Comment: erm...just like a screen saver... after particular time, the video view come out in front...if i touch the video view then remove from superview... go back to the main screen, if the screen keep tapping, the time keep resetting, if no tapping at all, after particular time the video pop out again.

Comment: i can only do it for 1 view...however, if at appdelegate it is really different case...

Comment: any suggestion if not using Timer...

Comment: see my edit to the answer, I hope it will help you

Comment: so sorry. i will improve next time... 1st time use not sure how to write in a code format. Thanks for your reminder with no solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this if it works for you.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginSignupVC")

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

If Not works, then I suggest using one initial `UIViewController` for this video screen and change to next screen when a video is completed.

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainVC")
        
        initialViewController.addChildViewController(self.player)
        initialViewController.view.addSubview(self.player.view)

after 5second i show this video view... but how i can go back to my main navigation view?

Comment: if i use back this code to go back my main navigation view...the navigation view tap function is gone...

Comment: if i use segue my    tapGesture.delegate = self
        window?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture) also gone for my navigation view controller

Comment: add navigation controller or specific view Controller as Root and then same self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController 
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

Comment: if i add tap gesture to the video view controller....then my navigation view controller(touch for all screen) the function gone...

Comment: self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController? = initialViewController like this?? but got error

Comment: 1st my whole app got the tap function by using  tapGesture.delegate = self
        window?.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)... after that i use your storyboard function to display the video...then i add tap gesture to the video view...tap and go back to the navigation main view and the tap function for whole app gone...

Comment: Harshad...the whole app tap gesture still can't work...after i remove the video view...the 1st time i launch the app still got tap gesture for whole app...after 5sec the video show up...then i tap the video go back to my main view...the main view's whole app tap gesture gone.

Comment: try to set tap gesture on ViewWillAppear

Comment: and want to ask...the video view i initialize at uinavigationcontroller or the uinavigationcontroller's first view?

Comment: The video view is set as rootView of a window if you want to navigate from it you need to as next Navigation controller as root like InitialView programmatically.

Comment: let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainNavigation")
        
        initialViewController.addChildViewController(self.player)
        initialViewController.view.addSubview(self.player.view)

Comment: i do like this... then add the player to the navigation view

Comment: bro, thanks....i share the best solution below edi...u go and have a look...btw thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.addChildViewController(self.player)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(self.player.view)

this is the best solution.

Credit to : senior Desmond

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution for the question

Comment: You are welcome... this is the most main window and can be access by every view controller also

Comment: I think the explanation is add the view controller and sub view to the main window’s root...is too deep if we go inside more, it is so dangerous 

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try adding video on launcher screen, or if you want the video should run, in that case you need to follow these simple steps

1. Add a Movie player on applicationDidLaunch
2. when video finishes on it return back method you need to load you app controller.

I hope this helps do let me know in case you need anything more to help.

[Edit as per the requirement]

I think you need to create a controller in the app delegate

1. you need to create a class function in your app delegate where you can add a movie player to the screen with auto play on.
2. also you need to maintain a timer, but be careful while using timer and read well about it, as it needs to be manage very carefully else results in various crashes.
3. You can manage the timer by getting touch events on the screen by the following logic like

   > if movieplayer is on screen then,  remove movie player else,
   >
   > invalidate timer and restart the timer
4. The function with timer will does the following things
   invalidate timer

> `add movie player on the window and bring it to the main screen.`

Comment: erm... Timer part i got idea...but the video view part i am not sure how to add to the window as a whole app...

Comment: u see the picture i added, which is the playvideo selector(function) for the start timer schedule... i not sure how to add the video view as a whole application at the playvideo selector(function)

Comment: @Gavin instead of changing rootviewcontroller you try adding and removing as subview and perform all this action on app delegate class, so it is accessible from all the classes